# email configuration: how to set up DNS and Plesk correctly?

Tags: email, dns, smtp, plesk, pop3

I am struggling to set up my server so that I can send and receive emails. Right now mails are neither sent nor received...

The server is Ubuntu 20 and Plesk Obsidian. I have web domain name hosting separate from my server.

On the web domain name host I have the following DNS configuration:

```
www                      3600  A      212.227.12.240
@                        3600  A      212.227.12.240
webmail                  3600  A      212.227.12.240
mail                     3600  A      212.227.12.240
@                        3600  MX     10 mail.blam-bti.com.
```

For the last line I also tried:

```
@                        3600  MX     10 blam-bti.com.
```

but this created the following error when trying to send to blam-bti.com

```
 Host or domain name not found. Name service error for
    name=blam-bti.com type=A: Host found but no data record of requested type
```

and on plesk I have the following DNS (set to Master):

```
_acme-challenge.blam-bti.com.       TXT gVzbL0yWSL33S-8dIam8Z8xk3tU02YOnlb1OUFIHnek
_dmarc.blam-bti.com.        TXT v=DMARC1; p=none
_domainconnect.blam-bti.com.        TXT domainconnect.plesk.com/host/serene-shockley.212-227-12-240.plesk.page/port/8443
blam-bti.com.       TXT v=spf1 +a +mx +a:serene-shockley.212-227-12-240.plesk.page -all
_pop3s._tcp.blam-bti.com.       SRV blam-bti.com.
_smtps._tcp.blam-bti.com.       SRV blam-bti.com.
_imaps._tcp.blam-bti.com.       SRV blam-bti.com.
blam-bti.com.       NS  ns2.blam-bti.com.
blam-bti.com.       NS  ns1.blam-bti.com.
blam-bti.com.       MX (10) mail.blam-bti.com.
ftp.blam-bti.com.       CNAME   blam-bti.com.
webmail.blam-bti.com.       A   212.227.12.240
ns1.blam-bti.com.       A   212.227.12.240
mail.blam-bti.com.      A   212.227.12.240
ns2.blam-bti.com.       A   212.227.12.240
blam-bti.com.       A   212.227.12.240
ipv4.blam-bti.com.      A   212.227.12.240
```

In plesk I have activated email, created an email address, opened the correct SMTP and POP3 / IMAP ports and secured the emails with a let's encrypt certificate.

Trying this:

```
nslookup -type=mx blam-bti.com
```

Brings back:

```
blam-bti.com    MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mail.blam-bti.com
```

Emails are not being sent or received.

Comment: Additional info: currently if I use webmail, emails get sent to internal addresses (ie: blam-bti.com) but not external addresses.

Comment: Hi, this is not a programming question so is off-topic for stack overflow.  Depending on your problem you may want to consider serverfault or superuser stackexchange sites.

Comment: I finally resolved this: resolution involved using an external DNS host (amazon's Route 53) and also correctly setting up my reverse DNS.